# Is restriction of scalars a pullback?

Tags: category-theory, modules

I am reading some handwritten notes, and scribbled next to a restriction of scalars functor, are the words "a pullback".

I don't understand why this might be the case.

In particular, consider a field $k$ with a map $\varphi:k\rightarrow A$ for $A$ an associative unital $k$-algebra. Then we consider the induced functor $\varphi_*:A-mod\rightarrow k-mod$ restriction of scalars.

> Is $\varphi_*$ the pullback of some diagram in the category of functors from $A$-mod to $k$-mod?

I know this a fairly strange question, but I just cant see what the scribbler had in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here -- don't you mean that $\varphi_* : A-\text{mod} \rightarrow k-\text{mod}$?

Comment: I most definitely do, I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: and should the question have also been changed?

Comment: sigh, yes it should have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sense in which "pullback" is being used here is the same sense it's being used in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback) Wikipedia article; that is, it's being used to refer to the process of "pulling back" a morphism $A \to \text{End}(R)$ (an $A$-module) along the morphism $k \to A$ to get a morphism $k \to \text{End}(R)$ (a $k$-module) by precomposition.  This is different from the categorical pullback.  I don't know why they're named the same.

**Edit:** Okay, so now I *do* know why they're named the same. To be brief, I think the historical motivation is that the pullback of [vector bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle) can be defined in both ways; see, for example, [this blog post](http://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/vector-bundles-grassmannians-and-characteristic-classes/) by Akhil Mathew.