# Meaning of pullback

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, limits-colimits

1. I was wondering if the following two
   meanings of pullback are related and
   how:

   - [In terms of Precomposition with a    function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback#Precomposition):

     > a function $f$ of a variable $y$, where $y$
     >   itself is a function of another
     >   variable $x$, may be written as a
     >   function of $x$. Then $f(y(x)) \equiv g(x)$ is the pullback of $f$ 
     >   by the
     >   function $y(x)$.
   - [In the context of Category
     theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28category_theory%29#Universal_property):

     > the pullback of the morphisms $f$ and
     >   $g$ consists of an object $P$ and two
     >   morphisms $p_1 : P \rightarrow X$ and
     >   $p_2 : P \rightarrow Y$ for which the
     >   diagram
     >
     > [image]
     >
     > commutes. Moreover, the pullback $(P, p_1, p_2)$ must be universal with
     >   respect to this diagram.
2. Also, is it possible to define
   pushforward/pushout in terms of
   composition of functions?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Have a look at this question of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10180/is-restriction-of-scalars-a-pullback

Comment: Consider $f = g \circ \alpha$. The universal property implies that the corresponding pullback satisfies (using Wikipedia notation current at the time of writing) $P = \text{dom } \alpha$, $p_1 = id$, $p_2 = \alpha$, so that $\alpha$ is the pullback of $f = g \circ \alpha$ along $\alpha$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a second to figure out what the Wikipedia page was saying.

Say you have a Fiber bundle $\pi:E \rightarrow B$ and a section (which is a function $s:B\rightarrow E$ such that $\pi(s(b))=b$ for $b \in B$.)

Also, say you have a function $f:B^\prime \rightarrow B$.  Then the pullback object $E^\prime$ can be defined as the set $E^\prime = \{(e,b^\prime) \in E \times B' : \pi(e)=f(b^\prime)\}$
Then you get an obvious pullback $\pi^\prime :E^\prime \rightarrow B^\prime$ defined by $\pi^\prime(e,b^\prime)=b^\prime$.

The key is that the pullback of $s$ is defined as $s^\prime:B^\prime \rightarrow E^\prime$ defined by $s^\prime(b^\prime) = (s(f(b^\prime)),b^\prime)$.

So the pullback of $s$ is (essentially) the composition of $s$ with $f$.

This pullback of $s$ can be made categorical because you have a square with top left object $B^\prime$ and bottom right $B$ defined with two paths: $B^\prime \xrightarrow{id} B^\prime \xrightarrow{f} B$ and $B^\prime \xrightarrow{s \circ f} E \xrightarrow{\pi} B$. So by the unversal property of $E^\prime$, there must be an $s^\prime:B^\prime \rightarrow E^\prime$ which, when composed with $\pi^\prime$ yields the identity.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the concepts of pullback and pushforward in terms of composition of functions only?

Answer (score 1):

The first article you linked to gave a relationship between the two notions using concepts from differential geometry.

Comment: Thanks! Can the relation be explained without referring to differential geometry, just based on the two concepts themselves?

Comment: I am not that well-versed in category theory, but it looks like saying that the diagram commutes means that the composition of f and p1 always gives the same result as the composition of g and p2; if p1 is invertible, then this means g is the pullback of f by the composition of p2 and the inverse of p1, in something like the earlier sense (if all of the morphisms are functions, then it is exactly like the earlier sense).

Comment: Thanks! Also is it possible to define pushforward/pushout in terms of composition of functions?

Comment: If g is the pullback of f by y, this means $g=f\circ y$; if y is invertible, then f is the pushforward of g by y, $f=g\circ y^{-1}$; I based this notion on a similar relationship between pushforward and pullback in differential geometry: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)#The_differential_of_a_smooth_map