# Intuition for pullback operation

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

In manifolds and complex geometry there is this thing called the pullback. Usually when I see it, its going backwards on maps that are going forwards. I've been told that it is just a composition of functions. I just need help understanding this concept.

Comment: join the club my friend.

Comment: Could you provide the definition that you are working with and tell us which part(s) you don't understand?

Comment: say you have a real-valued function $\phi:N\to\mathbb{R}$. you also have a  function $f:M\to N$. you'd like to get a real-valued function on $M$. how do you do it? you "pull it back" (from $N$ to $M$) by composition: $\phi\circ f$ now sends something in $M$ to something in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: symple, I understand this example.

Answer (score 10):

I have a sneaking suspicion that your deeper question is something like, "If $f:M \to N$ is a mapping, why do mathematicians focus on pulling back forms from $N$ to $M$ rather than (say) pushing forward vectors from $M$ to $N$? Where does the formal asymmetry come from?"

Briefly, the asymmetry comes from the requirement/constraint of *single-valuedness* in the definition of a mapping. To see why, first consider linear transformations and their effect on vectors and covectors; then consider smooth maps and their differentials.

---

If $T:U \to V$ is a linear transformation, then for each vector $u$ in $U$, the image $T(u)$ is a vector in $V$.

Dually, if $\lambda:V \to W$ is linear, the composition $T^{*}(\lambda) := \lambda \circ T:U \to W$ is linear. Particularly, $T$ "naturally" maps the dual space of $V$ to the dual space of $U$.

By contrast, there is no "natural" way to send a general linear mapping $\lambda:U \to W$ to a linear mapping $T_{*}(\lambda):V \to W$ (unless $T$ is an isomorphism, in which case there is the pullback $(T^{-1})^{*}$). The best we can do is define an "induced mapping" $T_{*}(\lambda)$ under the additional hypothesis that *$\lambda$ is constant on the level sets of $T$*, i.e., that if $T(u_{1}) = T(u_{2})$, then $\lambda(u_{1}) = \lambda(u_{2})$; in this event, we can define $T_{*}(\lambda)(v) = \lambda(u)$, where we pick an arbitrary $u$ with $T(u) = v$.

---

Now suppose $f:M \to N$ is a smooth mapping of smooth manifolds.

If $u$ is a tangent vector to $M$ at a point $p$, there is a "push-forward" tangent vector $f_{*}(u) = Df(p)u$ at $f(p)$ in $N$. Does this mean that vector fields push forward under $f$? No, it does not: A single point $q$ in $N$ may be the image of two or more points of $M$, say $f(p_{1}) = f(p_{2}) = q$. If $X$ is a vector field on $M$, there is no guarantee that
$$
Df(p_{1})X(p_{1}) = Df(p_{2})X(p_{2}),
$$
and so no guarantee that $f_{*}(X)$ is single-valued. (Or, $q$ may not be in the image of $f$ at all, so that $f_{*}(X)(q)$ literally has no value.) Instead, we must view $f_{*}(X)$ as a section of the "pullback bundle" $f^{*}(TN) \to M$, whose fibre over a point $p$ of $M$ is the tangent space $T_{f(p)}N$. This is meaningful and useful, but not as straightforward as we might naively have hoped.

By contrast, suppose $\omega$ is a smooth differential form on $N$. There is a well-defined smooth form $f^{*}\omega$ on $M$, defined in naive analogy to the pointwise situation, by
$$
f^{*}\omega(p)(u_{1}, \dots, u_{k})
  = \omega\bigl(f(p)\bigr)(f_{*}u_{1}, \dots, f_{*}u_{k}).
$$
Loosely, "everything in this definition works in our favor". Particularly, $f^{*}\omega$ has the same degree (here $k$) as $\omega$, and obeys the same exterior calculus:
$$
f^{*}(\omega \wedge \eta) = f^{*}\omega \wedge f^{*}\eta,\qquad
d(f^{*}\omega) = f^{*}(d\omega).
$$

If you'll permit (or forgive) a moment of rhapsodic philosophizing, this is one of those fundamental places in geometry where an apparent two-fold symmetry gets broken. In linear algebra, mappings and their dual mappings are, well, dual. There's arguably no reason to prefer one over the other. When we consider *families of linear transformations* arising as differentials of a single smooth mapping $f$, however, the formal symmetry between a (push-forward) linear transformation $f_{*}:T_{p}M \to T_{f(p)}N$ and its (pullback) dual $f^{*}:T_{f(p)}^{*}N \to T_{p}^{*}M$ breaks, causing us to prefer the pullback, essentially because mappings (i.e., $f$) are single-valued, but not generally bijective (invertible).

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes an example is better than a thousand words. Let's say you have these forms on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$:
    $$\omega^{1}= y\mbox{d}x-x\mbox{d}y-t\mbox{d}z+z\mbox{d}t,$$
$$\omega^{2}= t\mbox{d}x-z\mbox{d}y+y\mbox{d}z-x\mbox{d}t,$$
$$\omega^{3}= -z\mbox{d}x-t\mbox{d}y+x\mbox{d}z+y\mbox{d}t,$$
$$\omega^{4}= x\mbox{d}x+y\mbox{d}y+z\mbox{d}z+t\mbox{d}t.$$
And you want to pull them back into $S^3$. Then you need an application from $S^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Let's take this one
$$F\left(\psi,\,\theta,\,\phi\right)=\left(\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\psi\sin\theta\sin\phi,\sin\psi\cos\theta,\cos\psi\right).$$ This application sends a point of coordinates $\left(\psi,\,\theta,\,\phi\right)$ on the sphere to a point of coordinates $(x,y,z,w)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ where of course
$$x=\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi,$$
$$y=\sin\psi\sin\theta\sin\phi,$$
$$z=\sin\psi\cos\theta,$$
$$w=\cos\psi.$$
Now to do the pullback you have by definition
$$F^{*}(\omega^{i})=\omega^{i}(F_{*})$$
Then what you have to do is just differentiate 
$$dx = \cos\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi d\psi+\sin\psi\cos\theta\cos\phi d\theta-\sin\psi\sin\theta\sin\phi d\phi$$
$$dy = \cos\psi\sin\theta\sin\phi d\psi+\sin\psi\cos\theta\sin\phi d\theta+\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi d\phi$$
$$dz = \cos\psi\cos\theta d\psi-\sin\psi\sin\theta d\theta$$
$$dw = -\sin\psi d\psi.$$

Then you substitute inside the original formula (substituiting $dx,dy,dz,dw$ along with $x,y,z,w$ of course and you obtain the desired forms pulled back
$$\omega^{1}= \cos\theta\mbox{d}\psi-\sin\psi\cos\psi\sin\theta\mbox{d}\theta-\sin^{2}\psi\sin^{2}\theta\mbox{d}\phi,$$
$$ \omega^{2}= \sin\theta\cos\phi\mbox{d}\psi-\sin\psi\left(\sin\psi\sin\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta\cos\phi\right)\mbox{d}\theta-\sin\psi\sin\theta\left(\cos\psi\sin\phi+\sin\psi\cos\theta\cos\phi\right)\mbox{d}\phi,$$
$$ \omega^{3}= -\sin\theta\sin\phi\mbox{d}\psi-\sin\psi\left(\sin\psi\cos\phi+\cos\psi\cos\theta\sin\phi\right)\mbox{d}\theta -\sin\psi\sin\theta\left(\cos\psi\cos\phi-\sin\psi\cos\theta\sin\phi\right)\mbox{d}\phi,$$
$$ \omega^{4}= 0.$$
You notice that the last one is 0 because the form was variating only along the radius of the sphere. Anyhow you cannot obtain more than 3 indipendent form on $S^3$ and the first three are indipendent.
I think this example is complicated enough to let you practice, but simple enough to le you grasps what's going on here (which is effectively just the formalization of a change of variables).

Comment: Good example (+1)

Comment: Of course, you can pull back $x,y,z,t$ too. And if you do, the pullback forms can still be expressed by the original formulas $\omega^{1}= y\mbox{d}x-x\mbox{d}y-t\mbox{d}z+z\mbox{d}t,$ and so forth. The only difference is that $dx,dy,dz,dt$ are no longer linearly independent, so the formula is not unique.

Comment: You're right...

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you'll want, but too long for a comment, so [bear with me](https://i.imgflip.com/8uhl0.jpg).

You have a map $f\colon M \to N$ and something on $N$, say, a differential form or a covariant tensor field. You'd like to bring that object back to $M$, and the only thing you have so far relating $M$ and $N$ is $f$. Then you define the object on $M$ by computing it there in $N$, in adequate points and vectors. For example, if $\omega \in \Omega^1(N)$, you define $f^\ast\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ by $f^\ast\omega(p)(v) = \omega(f(p))({\rm d}f_p(v))$. Think a bit and convince yourself that this is the only thing that makes sense. We have that $\omega$ only "eats" points in $N$ (we only have $f(p)$) and vectors tangent no $N$ (we'll only have ${\rm d}f_p(v)$).

Same thing goes for differential forms of higher degree and arbritrary covariant tensor fields. You'll consider the point $f(p)$, and you'll "kick up" your arguments to $N$ via ${\rm d}f_p$. It is called "pullback" because we're using $\omega$ (which is forward) to define something back at $M$ - we're pulling back $\omega$ back to $M$.

Comment: Arbitrary *covariant* tensor fields.

Comment: Ah, I slipped! Thanks, I'll fix it.

Answer (score -2):

The general definition of a pullback:

Given two morphisms $f:X\to Z$ and $g:Y\to Z$, then a *pullback* of $f$ and $g$ (if it exist) is two morphisms $p_X:P\to X$ and $p_Y:P\to Y$
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    P @>p_Y>> Y\\
    @V p_X V V= @VV g V\\
    X @>>f> Z
\end{CD}
such that given morphisms $p'_X:P'\to X$ and $p'_Y:P'\to Y$ with 
\begin{CD}
    P' @>p'_Y>> Y\\
    @V p'_X V V= @VV g V\\
    X @>>f> Z
\end{CD}
there exist a unique morphism $\varphi:P'\to P$ such that 
$p'_X=p_X\varphi$ and $p'_Y=p_Y\varphi$.

I suspect that the morphism $\varphi$ sometimes is called pullback, but in category theory it's the two morphisms $p_X:P\to X$ and $p_Y:P\to Y$.

See also: [Universal Definition for Pullback](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68556/universal-definition-for-pullback)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about the pullback as encountered in differential geometry

Comment: @user2520938. The general definition is adequate for an answer.

Comment: It would be if these two notions of pullback are compatible, but as far as I know they aren't. Just two different concepts that happen to have to same name

Comment: @user2520938: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68556/universal-definition-for-pullback

Comment: I did not know that, interestng. In that case add this extra info to the answer, otherwise it's useless to the op

Comment: Also, I'm still convinced that the pullback that the op is talking about fits this definition

Comment: Where is the intuition in this...? I feel like you missed the point.