# Studying General Relativity got me stuck with some Differential Geometry issues regarding Hypersurfaces' Mappings

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, mathematical-physics

First of all, apologies if this question seems "rookie" or shows I lack basic concepts of Differential Geometry. I'm going straight to my question now:

Studying `3+1 Formalism`, there was a `mapping` between a $3D$-manifold and a $4D$-one.

It pushed  `vectors` from $3D$ to $4D$, and pulled `-forms` from $4D$ to $3D$.

I couldn't understand why you **can't** reverse map the `pull-back` and `push-forward` mapping, and I'm specifically referring to the [**Remark** at the start of page **21** (from page 19.5 starts the whole manifolds thingy)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0703035.pdf) , especially after pull-back mapping definition (one could do somewhat the same for vectors?).

I also saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891706/intuition-for-pullback-operation) here on S.E. but this one mainly refers how you can't go from $R^3 \rightarrow R^4$ which was actually done  for the vectors via `push-forward` mappings.

Thank you for your time. Any hint/source will help!

Comment: The remark that you've mentioned is saying that there is no **natural** way to define those reverse mapping, but not that you **can't** find a reverse at all (an example is given there). By **natural** we mean not-dependent on additional choices (e.g. a choice of coordinates). This is what the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1891939/2002) is trying to explain.

Comment: Alright. Sorry for the delay I REALLY tried hard to understand it. Couldn't really grasp the answer, especially since the hypersurface $\Sigma$ is embedded in in manifold $M$. (I didn't also get the $f_{*}u = Df(p)u$ push-forward relation which is referred below as well). Anyways, sorry if it's too much trouble. I studied some pre-graduate books and then the link I have above. I have read the book already, but it really bothers me that I don't get that part. @YuriVyatkin

Comment: It is not clear from your question and the comment what exactly you are struggling with, what is your motivation, why you need this reverse, and what sort of answer you expect to get here. This is why our members walk away. Please review your question.

Comment: By the way, welcome to our community and thank you for your question. Please note that this website is not an emergency help, but rather a space for collaborative learning. Consider your question as a contribution for us to grow, and you will get a better response.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Hi! Ty for welcoming me. It's not emergency help. I don't actually need it to "go through" it. It just bothers me that I don't understand it. Ok Can I delete the question and post a new one or should I edit this one?

Comment: You are very welcome. I think that it is better to edit this post as many times as you like, until it gets answered to your satisfaction. I am trying to help you to get a better outcome. Please edit the question to express more clearly, what exactly you don't understand. It may happen that you will answer your own question yourself, which is a great result too.